# is there a way to subset a dataset when read in using pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I see you can use use sample to return a random sample of items but is there anyway when reading in a csv file as a dataframe for example we only read in a specified random selection of rows of a specific number?

Is there anyway to read in the csv but pick 100 random rows from that csv.

Do I need to read in the full file or is there a different approach.

```
# Import the SparkSession library
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
  
# Create a spark session using getOrCreate() function
spark_session = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  
# Read the CSV file
data_frame=csv_file = spark_session.read.csv('/content/student_data.csv',
                            sep = ',', inferSchema = True, header = True)
  
# Extract random sample through sample function using 
# withReplacement (value=True) and fraction as arguments 
data_frame.sample(True,0.8).collect()
```

Comment: Do you know the number of lines in this file?

Comment: How random does it need to be?

Comment: so what to specify to choose n number of rows randomly in the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess my main question is why are you doing this?  Is the data file real big?  Just read it into memory (RDD) like you are doing and then sample.

The idea behind spark is to not worry about file I/O.  Yes, you can write the following python to read in a file that has a row delimiter of CR/LF.

```
#
# Not Recommended - read in file - line by line
#

with open('/content/student_data.csv') as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break
```

The next question is how many lines to get a random sampling of 100 rows?  Do you take every third row.  Then we need at least 300 rows of data?  What happens if you only have 250 rows.  I suggest not going down this path since it is truly not random picking out of all data.

Again, if data size is the concern, then I suggest you store the data in a partitioned file.  I am going to show you how to select a partition, then sample the partition and take the first 100 rows.

Azure Databricks has sample data sets.  We are going to use the airline dataset that is stored as a partitioned CSV file.

[image]

We can see there are 1919 partitions.

```
# pick a partition
n = random.randrange(1, 1919)
s = '{:05d}'.format(n)
print(f"This is the random partition = {s}")

# read data
path = "/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-" + s
df1 = spark.read.load(path,format="csv",sep=",",inferSchema="true",header="true" )

# get partition count
c = df1.count()
print(f"This is the whole partition count {c}")

# get sample count
df2 = df1.sample(True, 0.01)
c = df2.count()
print(f"This is the sample count {c}")

# grab first 100
df3 = df2.limit(100)
c = df3.count()
print(f"This is the first 100 rows {c}")
```

[image]

To summarize, for very large datasets you should partition the data by a number N and randomly pick a partition and then sample and select the data.  This took only 8 seconds to perform.  If we had to do the whole dataset, it would have been 1919 x 600K rows to read instead of 600K rows.  Reverting back to Python I/O will cause the program to not be distributed and run at the executor node.  In short, partitioning is your friend with large datasets.

Comment: what does sample 0.01 do? It take 1 % of the the whole dataset is it?

Is there a way to include column name e.g id and do a random sample but include all ids = 1 and id=2 but also other random ids. I could use filter but it will only select ids I choose in sample

Comment: Take df1 dataframe and split.  Choose all ids in (1, 2, etc) as df1a.  Choose all ids not in (1, 2, etc).  The 0.01 is 1/100 random sampling.  Then I take the first 100.  Union df1a with the results.  You have two sets of logic.  Therefore two dataframes to union into final result.